# Parent onChange sets child property to true

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Form (parent) component:

```
export default {
  template: `
    <form name="form" class="c form" v-on:change="onChange">
      <slot></slot>
    </form>`,
  methods: {
    onChange:function(){
      console.log("something changed");
    }
  }
};
```

and a c-tool-bar component (child) that is (if existing) inside the c-form's slot

```
export default {
  template: `
    <div class="c tool bar m006">
      <div v-if="changed">
         {{ changedHint }} 
      </div>
      <!-- some other irrelevant stuff -->  
    </div>`,
  props: {
    changed: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    changedHint: String
  }
};
```

What I want to achieve is, that when onChange of `c-form` gets fired the function
checks if the child c-tool-bar is present && it has a changedHint text declared (from backend) it should change the `c-tool-bar`'s prop "changed" to true and the c-bar-tool updates itself so the `v-if="changed"` actually displays the changedHint. I read the vue.js docs but I don't really know where to start and what the right approach would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the two components like this:

```
<parent-component></parent-component>
```

You will be passing in the `:changed` prop a variable defined in the parent component in `data()`. Note the `:`, we are using [dynamic props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props), so once the prop value is changed in the parent it will update the child as well.
To change the display of the hint, change the value of the variable being passed in as prop to the child component:

```
export default {
  template: `
    <form name="form" class="c form" v-on:change="onChange">
      <child-component :changed="shouldDisplayHint"></child-component>
    </form>`,
  data() {
    return {
      shouldDisplayHint: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onChange:function(){
      this.shouldDisplayHint = true; // change the value accordingly
      console.log("something changed");
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: That's good idea too. He can choose between using $refs and passing props with one-way binding

Comment: Do i need to do changes to the child template? i get the following error: [Vue warn]: Property or method "shouldDisplayHint" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
(found in component <c-bar-tool>)

Comment: Have you added `shouldDisplayHint` in the data property in the parent component?

Comment: Yes, i changed the parent's data and method as you stated. Do i put the :changed="shouldDisplayHint" in the template markup or when i call the component like <c-bar-tool :changed="shouldDisplayHint"> ?

Comment: When you call the component

Comment: vue.js?v=2.2.3:523 [Vue warn]: Property or method "shouldDisplayHint" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
(found in root instance)... probably because cform isnt my root instance? [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/E5luw)

Comment: Yeah that works but won't if i do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/49gptnad/87/

Comment: Yes, my bad, sorry! I have updated also the answer to remove the use of slots

Comment: Well is there any way to make it work with slots? Not every cform has this child component :(

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to use `$refs`.

When you will create your child component inside your parent component, you should have something like: `<c-tool-bar ref="child">` and then you can use it in your parent component code:

```
methods: {
    onChange:function(){
      this.$refs.child.(do whatever you want)
    }
  }
```

Hope it helps but in case of any more questions: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs